# How to correct the drift in MPU9250 IMU using DMP MotionApps v4.1

Tags: quaternions, mpu, dmp, imu

I'm trying to provide a visual orientation of a device in 3D using Qt. For this,I have integrated the DMP MotionApps v4.1 for a MPU9250 and obtained the Quaternion values from the MPU's FIFO register. This works perfectly fine. But when the device is left stable over a period of time (say after 20 mins), the Quaternion value(mostly Qz and sometimes Qx), start drifting slowing and my visual orientation gets changed. Is there a way to correct this drift with DMP being used? Any suggestions please..

Comment: Be sure , use of magnetometer is ON.

Comment: @minorlogic yes i'm using the magnetometer..